# Are there intelliSense / autocomplete plugins for gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am starting on a new project using the Gutenberg WordPress block editor. The ability to create custom blocks and consume api data using withSelect seems very useful, but I feel I am really missing any kind of autocomplete, especially as the current documentation is not ideal.

I primarily work in VSCode so I am primarily interested in any IntelliSense plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this out. The problems is that if you import your variables like this:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
```

Now, if you start typing `__(` or `registerBlockType(`, no intellisense is triggered.

This problem is solved if you import with the following statements:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
```

This will load from your node_modules folder, so if this throws an error, you may need to install the dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev @wordpress/blocks @wordpress/i18n
```

However, this introduces a last potential problem: importing the modules in your bundle is not necessary, since WordPress has already loaded the wp object. So there is no need to add all this code again in our webpack bundle.

If you created your blocks using `create-guten-block`, you are set at this point, because create-guten-block already takes care of this problem automatically.

If you use a custom Webpack installation however, you will need to make sure to add these modules as **externals** inside your **webpack.config.js** file, like so:

```
  externals: {
    "@wordpress/blocks": ["wp","blocks"],
    "@wordpress/i18n": ["wp","i18n"]
  }
```